# Cannot find the Ionic CSS class documentation or code for "item-list-detail"

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

In the following code (taken from this great tutorial: http://devdactic.com/ionic-image-zooming/), where can I find the documentation or code for the CSS class="item item-list-detail"?

I can't find this in the ionic online documentation (http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/). And "item-list-detail" does not appear in any other files in the entire project. It'd be good to see exactly what CSS code is this item-list-detail. Is there an easy way to find CSS class documentation or code?

```
  <a class="item item-list-detail">
    <ion-scroll direction="x">
      <img ng-repeat="image in allImages" ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages($index)" class="image-list-thumb"/>
    </ion-scroll>
  </a>
```

Comment: Can inspect any element in the dom in browser dev tools live html view and see all css rules that apply to any element in ranked order. Can do live edits in page also to test rules

Comment: Cool, I did that and it's useful but am still confused about what "item-list-detail" is doing. If I edit the attribute deleting the "item-list-detail" part, all the css rules are the same.

Comment: The Ionic website doesn't have anything named "item-list-detail" (http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/). Maybe it's something from another framework or some CSS thing I'm not aware of?

Comment: the same inspector tells you exactly what file the rules are in and even provides line numbers line